# Getting the values of the group of textfields in single variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, radio-button

I am trying to get the values from the group of text fields which looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evdNw.jpg). First question and options field will be available by default. When the user click, add text field button, one more set will be added. When the download button is clicked, it should display the entire group values in the one variable.

I wanna get the output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TeNK.jpg).

If the user selects the radio button, that should be accompanied by "#" in-front, if not by "*".

I can get the values separately for each questions. But, couldn't do that for entire group and store it in the single instance. I have implemented for loop too. But, something is going wrong.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <form class="col-sm-12"> 

                        <div id="textfields">
                           <div id="entireText0">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="textarea0">Question</label>
                                                <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea0" rows="2"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <label>Options</label>
                            </div>

                            <div id="optionfields">
                                <div class="form-group" id="myForm0">
                                        <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                  <div class="input-group-text">
                                                  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="text" name="txtbox" id="textbox1" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
                                        </div>
                                        </br>
                                        <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                  <div class="input-group-text">
                                                  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="text" name="txtbox" id="textbox2" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
                                        </div>
                                    </br>
                                    <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                              <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" name="txtbox" id="textbox3" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
                                    </div>
                                    </br>
                                    <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                              <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" name="txtbox" id="textbox4" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
                                    </div>
                                    </br>                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>



                <button type="button" id ="button0" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addTextFields();">Add Text field</button>
                <br/><br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="selectedRadioButton();">Download</button>

            </form>
```

JS:

```
function selectedRadioButton() {
            for(textid=0;textareaid>=textid;textareaid--,textid++){
            var question= document.getElementById("textarea"+textid).value; 
            console.log("question",question);           
            question_gi= "::Q"+(textid+1)+"::"+question;
            var selectedArray=["["];
            $('.form-group #myForm+textid+ input[type=radio]').each(function() {
                var value = "*";
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                value = "#";
                }
                value += $($(this).closest('.input-group').find("input[type=text]")).val();
                selectedArray.push(value);
            });
            selectedArray.push("]");
            var newArr = selectedArray.join(',').replace(/,/g, ' ').split();
            entire_gi= question_gi+ "%0d%0a" +newArr;
            finalvalue=[];
            finalvalue += entire_gi[textid];
            console.log(finalvalue);
              }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all of the radio buttons and all of the text inputs for forming the final String.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <form class="col-sm-12"> 

                        <div id="textfields">
                           <div id="entireText0">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="textarea0">Question</label>
                                                <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea0" rows="2"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <label>Options</label>
                            </div>

                            <div id="optionfields">
                                <div class="form-group" id="myForm0">
                                        <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                  <div class="input-group-text">
                                                  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="text" name="txtbox" id="textbox1" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
                                        </div>
                                        </br>
                                        <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                  <div class="input-group-text">
                                                  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="text" name="txtbox" id="textbox2" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
                                        </div>
                                    </br>
                                    <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                              <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" name="txtbox" id="textbox3" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
                                    </div>
                                    </br>
                                    <div class="input-group col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                              <div class="input-group-text">
                                              <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" name="txtbox" id="textbox4" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
                                    </div>
                                    </br>                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>



                <button type="button" id ="button0" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addTextFields();">Add Text field</button>
                <br/><br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="selectedRadioButton();">Download</button>

            </form>
<script>
function selectedRadioButton() {
   var textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea0');
   var question = textarea.value;
   var str = "::Q1::"+question+"\n";
   var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
   str += "[";
   var textinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
   for(let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
     str += (radios[i].checked)? "#": "*";
     str += textinputs[i].value;
   }
   str += "]";
   console.log(str);
}
</script>
```